# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path

Tags: java, hadoop, lzo, hadoop-lzo

I got: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path` so i followed: 
[http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UsingLzoCompression] so after running

`$ant compile-native`

I get many errors:

```
$ ant compile-native
Buildfile: /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/build.xml

ivy-download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.0.0-rc2/ivy-2.0.0-rc2.jar
      [get] To: /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/ivy/ivy-2.0.0-rc2.jar
^Cmycomputer@mycomputerD_LAP:~/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0$ clear

mycomputer@mycomputerD_LAP:~/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0$ ant compile-native
Buildfile: /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/build.xml

ivy-download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.0.0-rc2/ivy-2.0.0-rc2.jar
      [get] To: /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/ivy/ivy-2.0.0-rc2.jar
      [get] Not modified - so not downloaded

ivy-init-dirs:

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-init-antlib:

ivy-init:
[ivy:configure] :: Ivy 2.0.0-rc2 - 20081028224207 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
:: loading settings :: file = /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/ivy/ivysettings.xml

ivy-resolve-common:
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: com.hadoop.gplcompression#Hadoop-GPL-Compression;working@mycomputerD_LAP
[ivy:resolve]   confs: [common]
[ivy:resolve]   found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4 in default
[ivy:resolve]   found junit#junit;3.8.1 in default
[ivy:resolve]   found commons-logging#commons-logging-api;1.0.4 in maven2
[ivy:resolve] :: resolution report :: resolve 162ms :: artifacts dl 6ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      common      |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ivy-retrieve-common:
[ivy:retrieve] :: retrieving :: com.hadoop.gplcompression#Hadoop-GPL-Compression
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [common]
[ivy:retrieve]  0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/7ms)
No ivy:settings found for the default reference 'ivy.instance'.  A default instance will be used
DEPRECATED: 'ivy.conf.file' is deprecated, use 'ivy.settings.file' instead
:: loading settings :: file = /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/ivy/ivysettings.xml

init:

compile-java:
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/build.xml:191: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 9 source files to /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/build/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:27: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configurable;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:28: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockCompressorStream;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BlockCompressorStream
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.hadoop.io.compress
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BlockDecompressorStream
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.hadoop.io.compress
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CompressionCodec
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.hadoop.io.compress
    [javac] /home/mycomputer/tmp/hadoop-gpl-compression-0.1.0/src/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzoCodec.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionInputStream;
```

help!

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using ?

Comment: I don't have hadoop on my dev env.  I just wish to do some local development with spark on local files.